# Java Generics: how handle raw type member variable and avoid warnings?

Tags: java, generics, warnings

I have a class that has a raw type member variable called `Argument<T>`. The class is meant to simply wrap around this type, and assign all values via the constructor in a generic way, because the type of `Argument` and of the parameters passed to the constructor is not known at compile time.

```
public class ArgumentWrapper {

    private Argument argument;

    public ArgumentImplementation(Class<?> type, String name, 
            Object defaultValue, Set<?> allowedValues, 
            Comparable<?> lowerBound, Comparable<?> upperBound) {
        argument = new Argument<>(type);
        argument.setName(name);
        argument.setDefaultValue(defaultValue);
        argument.setAllowedValues(allowedValues);
        argument.setLowerBound(lowerBound);
        argument.setUpperBound(upperBound);
    }

    // some getters...

}
```

Now in my code I get a lot of warnings saying

```
Argument is a raw type. References to generic type Argument<T> should be 
parameterized
```

at the member and

```
Type safety: The method setDefaultValue(Object) belongs to the raw type Argument.
References to generic type Argument<T> should be parameterized
```

where the constructor parameters are assigned to it.

I know I cannot change the member to `private Argument<?> argument;` because then I get errors when the generic parameters are assigned to it in the constructor.

What is your recommendation to handle this? How do I avoid these warnings without introducing errors? How can I handle the generic type member variable different / better?

Comment: Your ArgumentWrapper, since it wraps a generic tyupe, should also be a generic type.

Comment: Sounds legit. So how would I implement this in my case? If I simply change the class to `public class ArgumentWrapper<T>` and the member variable to `private Argument<T> argument;` I introduce errors at the constructor. I'm not sure how to handle them. I will accept the answer that shows me how to do it in my example.

Comment: How about showing us your updated code, and showing the complete and exact error message?

Comment: Thanks I got it now. Anyway, I prefer getting an answer with examples then a brief one where I have to deal with errors (of my own stupidity) and make the question-answer process too long... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of a comment and some trying back and forth I got the answer myself.

The `ArgumentWrapper` class should be generic, and the generic type `T` should be used everywhere.

```
public class ArgumentWrapper<T> {

    private Argument<T> argument;

    public ArgumentImplementation(Class<T> type, String name, 
            T defaultValue, Set<T> allowedValues, 
            Comparable<T> lowerBound, Comparable<T> upperBound) {
        argument = new Argument<T>(type);
        argument.setName(name);
        argument.setDefaultValue(defaultValue);
        argument.setAllowedValues(allowedValues);
        argument.setLowerBound(lowerBound);
        argument.setUpperBound(upperBound);
    }

    // some getters...

}
```